# Latex macros in Jupyter (iPython) notebook not rendered by github

Tags: github, macros, latex, jupyter

I have a markdown cell in a Jupyter notebook (.ipynb) with the following content.

```
$\newcommand{\paren}[1]{\left(#1\right)}$
$\paren{\beta^2}$
```

The file is in a Github repository. The LaTex macro application is not rendered by Github.

Here is how it looks:

[image]

The markdown cell, however, is rendered properly when I open is locally as a Jupyter notebook. 
[image]

Is there a way to make this work? Note that the file is in a private Github repo, so I can not use nbviewer.