# How to define a LaTeX macro in a Markdown cell of a Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, latex, markdown

I want to define a macro in a Markdown cell of a Jupyter notebook. But it seems that we cannot define it.

For example, I want to define a macro which formats vectors.
The code in the cell is:

```
\newcommand{\vect}[1]{{\mathbf{\boldsymbol{{#1}}}}}

This is the vector $\vect{x}$.
```

The rendering is:

[image: The macro is unused.]

PS
The question was asked at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/281535/latex-macros-in-markdown, but it is not relevant directly to LaTeX, and the question was tagged as off-topic.

Answer (score 10):

The way to define a macro in a Jupyter cell is to put a dollar in front of and after the macro.

```
$\newcommand{\vect}[1]{{\mathbf{\boldsymbol{{#1}}}}}$
This is the vector $\vect{x}$.
```

and the rendering is:

[image: Correct rendering]

PS
This is the trick used at [Latex macros in Jupyter (iPython) notebook not rendered by github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44773602/latex-macros-in-jupyter-ipython-notebook-not-rendered-by-github), but the topic is slightly different.