# Make new command in .ipynb markdown in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, markdown, katex

I am trying to create new commands for markdown in an ipython notebook file in VSCode, but am having trouble doing so

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65864550/how-to-define-a-latex-macro-in-a-markdown-cell-of-a-jupyter-notebook) post shows an example which (kinda) works in jupyter notebook:

```
$\newcommand{\vect}[1]{{\mathbf{\boldsymbol{{#1}}}}}$
This is the vector $\vect{x}$.
```

But pasting this exact code in VSCode, I get the error:

```
ParseError: KaTeX parse error: Undefined control sequence: \vect at position 1: \vect{x}.
```

So it seems the new command does not get created. Am grateful for any solution

Comment: I opened an issue on VS Code repository for this a few months back: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/125425

Answer (score 1):

[Issue 125425](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/125425) opened by [Chandresh Pant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/713152/chandresh-pant) and mentioned in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71254191/make-new-command-in-ipynb-markdown-in-vscode#comment127198670_71254191) seems to be solved for VSCode 1.69 (June 2022)

See [PR 148006](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/148006) and [commit acb156d](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/acb156d6fb0dc451f427748d5f68774f17cc96fd):

> In order to make macros defined by the author persistent between KaTeX elements, we need to pass one shared macros object into every call to the renderer.
> KaTeX will insert macros into that object and since it continues to exist between calls, macros will persist.
>
> See [KaTeX docs](https://katex.org/docs/api.html#persistent-macros).
>
> [image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1220427/164980400-148fbeea-c928-44eb-819e-dd74179ab16b.png]

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Markdown + Math](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=goessner.mdmath) extension by [Stefan Goessner](https://github.com/goessner) which supports macros. It works really well on my setup.

We can also define macros in the user settings, e.g.

```js
"mdmath.macros": {
    "\\vect" "{\\mathbf{\\boldsymbol{{#1}}}}"
}
```

or in a separate json file as follows.

```js
"mdmath.macroFile": "/path/to/macros.json"
```