# Cannot render LaTeX in VScode Jupyter Notebook

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, katex

I have homework in VScode Jupyter Notebook but I get a lot of ParseError in it when displaying the LateX. The error is

```
ParseError: kaTeX parse error:Undefined control sequence.
```

for example one of the Markdown cells is

```
$\newcommand{\vect}[1]{{\mathbf{\boldsymbol{{#1}}}}}$
This is the vector $\vect{x}$.
```

and the jupyter cannot render it I guess? (I am not very familar with LateX) and will get the following error [parse error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82DQt.jpg)

Comment: Checkout my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71254191/make-new-command-in-ipynb-markdown-in-vscode/71272643#71272643) to the same question.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your advice. I have downloaded the Markdown + Math extension and now I can use the macro in the .md file but it is still not working for the jupyter notebook, are you sure macros can work in your jupyter notebook file?

Comment: It works for me! Have you executed the cell with your macro?

Comment: I get this error occur if I have a line of mathematics followed by text outside the line, e.g.
$$ x = y $$,
where the comma is outside the line. This will parse but if I later try and add inline maths e.g. $x$, it no longer works. So maybe check you're not doing that cause it's not easy to spot